# Resend a message automatically from Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have an Outlook account at work (Windows 10), and unfortunately, I cannot open this account on any other computer.

And the biggest problem is that it is necessary to use this account in professional communication with the parties involved in the work, which somewhat undermines me, as in some cases I have to go to the workplace to send a message even though my work requires constant and large movement.

So I tried to find a way to resend a message via my e-mail, after receiving a message from my Gmail account with accurate details of the sender,... etc., so that he would resend it automatically without any intervention from me.

Is there a solution to this dilemma?

Comment: Use Outlook Advanced Rules to pick the condition and send.

Comment: In many cases, the server has webmail capabilities. Although it is unsure what kind of account it is, most workspaces use Exchange, and an Exchange server usually has a webmail address too. This would allow you to use any computer with a browser to access your email the same way as gmail does. Ask your IT staff what the webmail address is, and who knows, you get lucky. :)

Comment: Another option could be to remote control your work pc from another pc or device, using a client such as AnyDesk. That would effectively allow you to use your Outlook from any computer.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of your mail account? Could you open the account in web mail?

Based on my knowledge, if your mail account is exchange account, you could assign [send as permission](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/mailbox-permissions?view=exchserver-2019) for your e-mail account. The permission allow your e-mail account send as your work account.

Or you could configure inbox rule, all mails will be sent to your work account will be forward to your e-mail account, if the behavior is available for compliance management in your organization.

Comment: Is there any updates?

Comment: I apologize for the late reply, regarding the email, I can't open it in the browser meaning it's only within the company's network. Regarding the transfer of messages that send to me to the work mail, I did this before and it works fine, but what I want to do is the opposite. For example, when I receive an email, I cannot answer it using my mail, and this forces me to go to the workplace to do so, so I want to send an email from the work mail, by sending a letter to my mail at work, then the latter will automatically forward it to the person I want